# How to make android options menu visible even no visible entries?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu

I have a Fragment that should have its options menu with a variety of entries that I add at runtime. When the fragment starts, all entries are invisible, and the options menu doesn't show up. In onPrepareOptionsMenu I set a variety of entries as visible. However, if nothing is visible when the fragment starts, the options menu doesn't show up at all.

My current workaround is to make an option visible by default then make it invisible if it's not needed, but this seems hacky.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this: if in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, everything is invisible, and you make items visible in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`, you do not get the overflow menu. But, if in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, 1+ items are visible, and then you make them invisible in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`, the overflow menu behaves as you want (visible/invisible based on whether any individual item is visible)? If so, that feels like a bug.

Comment: I'm actually setting one item as visible in the first line of onPrepareOptionsMenu(), then going through and adding everything else that should be added, and then removing the first item at the if it's not supposed to be visible. In onCreateOptionsMenu I just inflate the view (which has everything invisible)

Comment: Hmmm... that still feels like a bug. You could try calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on the hosting `Activity` and see if that helps. Or, try calling `setMenuVisibility(true)` on the fragment. Or, try calling `setMenuVisibility(false)`, then `setMenuVisibility(true)`. None of that should be needed, and I don't know that they're vastly better hacks than what you have.